# Retrieve value from password field

Tags: javascript, http, d3.js

On a page [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/p6zp1zem/2/), what kind of code could I write to prevent the page from sending a GET request (or a POST request)?

Page:

```
<body>
    <p>Let's do the login thing
        <br>
    </p>
    <form id="keyform">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="midform">
                        <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="ID">
                        <br>
                        <input type="password" id="key" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="submitform">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Code:

```
d3.select("#keyform").on("submit", function () {
    console.log(d3.select('#key').property("value"));
    return false;
});
```

I intend to capture the value of the password on submit, run it through md5 and send it to a server to compare with a hash in a database. But clicking "submit" causes the page to send a GET, which is undesirable.

Comment: Set the form method to 'post'

Comment: Change the input from submit to text and just process it yourself.

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik that won't work, because I need to md5 it **before** POSTing it.

Comment: @Craicerjack in that case, how could I hide the text field a la "type=password" does?

Comment: @Sky change this `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">` input type and call an action to handle the form yourself or set the form action to a function and handle it yourself - like @Rajagopal answer below. You dont need to touch the password input

Answer (score 0):

Add a script tag and write a function to change the password value like this...

```
<script>
function encrypt(){

    var pwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
    // do md5 on pwd and store it back to pwd.
    document.getElementById('password').value = pwd;

    //false to prevent submit, or replace true if you need the form to be submitted after executing the above code inside the function (updating the password field).
    return false;
}
</script>
```

and trigger the function on submit of the form in form tag like this.

```
<form id="keyform" onsubmit='return encrypt()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I tried making the form **not** submit, by changing the button's id and type to be "login" and "button", respectively, and linking `onSubmit()` to onClick. But this made the event not fire at all, meaning I had no way to access the text box values.

Then I tried deleting the form, meaning I had two inputs and a button just floating around. This time, the onClick *did* fire and I was able to read the values of ID and password. I hypothesize that  locks up the data so that it can't be accessed until submit.

I also suspect that removing form means I no longer have any built-in protection for passwords, since I can programmatically intercept the text field's value.